# Is it possible to upload file (images) to BlobStore programmatically without the reference to Forms?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jakarta-ee, blobstore

Is it possible to upload file (images) to BlobStore programmatically without the reference to Forms (jsp.... )   ?

I've searched all  related topics to my problem  but  no item deals exactly with what i need.

I will be very grateful if you help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not anymore: there used to be a [Files API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/#Java_Writing_files_to_the_Blobstore), but it's now deprecated.

You should use Google Cloud Storage instead, which has all features of blobstore and also has [Client Library](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlecloudstorageclient/) allowing you to programmatically store data.

Comment: GCS is the preferred way now. But you can send a multi-part form programmatically to the blobstore. Here is an example: https://gist.github.com/voscausa/9222732

Comment: @vocausa thanks also but my project is written in Java, not Python.

Answer (score 0):

Use [AjaxFileUpload](http://www.codeforge.com/read/107474/ajaxfileupload.js__html)

It internally uses form submit in an iframe and gives us full control over the upload.

As you are using BlobStore, the work around will be,

1. Refer the file tag (not necessarily it should be inside a form) to the fileupload.js
2. Get the Blobstore session url for each upload.
3. Assign the session url to the url of the fileupload.js